# “No rows were georeferenced” error in CartoDB

Tags: carto, error

I am trying to geolocate my data by department name and country, but receive an error:

No rows were georeferenced It seems that some of your rows didn't finish successfully. Perhaps these rows contained empty values or perhaps we just didn't know what the values meant. We encourage you to take a look and try again.

Basically, I have an .xls dataset with columns: Homicides - that contain data on homicides rate; Department - the department where this homicide rate was registered; Province - the province to which each department belongs and Country - Argentina. I've been trying to map the location for the homicide rate, but I did not succeed with even one department. What might I be doing wrong?

Comment: Could you share your data? CartoDB should be able to detect départements, but your error could be due to you not having enough quota left in your account. Try checking it or geocoding a smaller table to check!

Answer (score 1):

CartoDB definitely georefs Argentinian provinces, but if departamentos are failing you can get their polygons here: http://www.ign.gob.ar/archivos/sig250/DEPARTAMENTOS.zip. If IGN's licensing allows you can import that to CartoDB, then Edit > Merge with your homicides dataset. Use a column join based on DEPARTAMENTOS zip's fna and your dataset's column containing department names. You only need the_geom column from DEPARTAMENTOS zip.

Answer (score 0):

If this turns out to be your quota getting in the way, you might try collapsing your geographic fields to a table of UNIQUE departments (frequency analysis), geocoding that (presumably) much smaller dataset, then joining those geocodes back to the larger dataset. I geocoding 170k photos a few years back, but only had 4k unique locations, which was a far more manageable job than geocoding 170k.